# uima ruta create two annotations in one ruta rule

Tags: uima, ruta

I'm writing ruta scirpts to capture sbp&dbp annotations from the text like "bp: 120/80mmHg". What I want to obtain are : 
   Sign: name="sbp", value=120, unit=mmHg 
   Sign: name="dbp", value=80, unit=mmHg

Anyone can indicate me how to do that? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Doing this correctly and in the right way requires a lot of additional resources and analysis engines, e.g., concept mapping mabye against loinc, detecting arbitrary complex  numeric values, detecting units and measurements, also in slash enums, normalization against si base units and so on.

Here's a simple Ruta script as a initial prototype (tested with 2.6.1):

```
DECLARE BloodPressure (DOUBLE systolic, DOUBLE diastolic, STRING unit);

DECLARE Unit, BloodPressureIndicator;

// mock annotations, replace with dictionary or unit parser
"mmHg" -> Unit;
"bp" -> BloodPressureIndicator;

DOUBLE d1, d2;
(BloodPressureIndicator COLON? NUM{PARSE(d1)} SPECIAL.ct=="/" NUM{PARSE(d2)} u:Unit)
    {-> CREATE(BloodPressure, "systolic" = d1, "diastolic" = d2, "unit" = u.ct)};
```

and  here an example creating two annotations of different types:

```
DECLARE BloodPressure (DOUBLE value, STRING unit);
DECLARE BloodPressure SBP, DBP;

DECLARE Unit, BloodPressureIndicator;

// mock annotations, replace with dictionary or unit parser
"mmHg" -> Unit;
"bp" -> BloodPressureIndicator;

DOUBLE d1, d2;
(BloodPressureIndicator COLON? 
    NUM{PARSE(d1) -> CREATE(SBP, "value" = d1, "unit" = u.ct)} 
    SPECIAL.ct=="/" 
    NUM{PARSE(d2) -> CREATE(DBP, "value" = d2, "unit" = u.ct)}
    u:Unit);
```

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Comment: Ah, ok I completely missed the title of the question. I'll modify my answer.